# Guidance on basic python assignment

Tags: python

Need to create a python code to provide a list of tuples (searched words, list of occurrences).
the searched words are listed in a Thesaurus which need to be searched in a series of documents in a Corpus.

Any suggestion/guidance?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. However, your question is too broad for this site. Please check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you read the file, you could simply use split on space to get a list of words. This however would include punctuation.  To remove the punctuation you could get a list of punctuation from "string" library's "punctuation" attribute and replace the occurences of punctuation in the words list obtained above with empty string,"". Your words might have special symbols such as "/" to represent or. Then you would need regular expressions to extract the words.